# Отображение данных пользователя из БД на всех страницах

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Для того чтобы логин, авторизовавшегося пользователя, отображался на всех страницах я сделал так:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
...
<footer>
  <p>Логин: @User.Identity.Name</p>
</footer>
...
```

Но мне надо еще отобразить наименование школы, связанной с данным логином.
Дел в том, что есть таблица в БД:

**dbo.school**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и логины (User.Identity.Name) совпадают с полем SchoolID. Как теперь выгрузить соответствующее поле SchoolName и отобразить его на каждой странице сайта вместе с логином.

Конечно же саму информацию выгрузить я могу, реализуя интерфейс `IRepository`:

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  private cokoContext context = new cokoContext();
  IRepository<school> schoolRepository;  
}

public HomeController()
{
  schoolRepository = new SchoolRepository(context); 
}
```

Но как именно дальше должен сработать `Контроллер` со `View`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать частичное представление.

Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetFooter()
{
    if (Session["footer"] == null)
        Session["footer"] = _schoolRepository.GetById(User.Identity.Name);

    School entity = (School)Session["footer"];

    var model = new FooterViewModel(User.Identity.Name, entity.SchoolName);

    return View(model);
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model Namespace.Web.Models.FooterViewModel

@{
    Layout = null; // что бы не зациклился
}

<footer>
  <p>Логин: @Model.UserLogin</p>
  <p>Школа: @Model.SchoolName</p>
</footer>
```

Layout:

```
<!-- -->
@{ Html.RenderAction("GetFooter", "Home"); }
<!-- -->
```